# How to button show and hide html form with angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm still learning to programme.
How I can show and hide two not very different HTML forms with a button in Angular?
I have a code but it shows only two forms and doesn't hide them.
I want to display these two forms on one row. How I can do this?
Please help me.
My HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="showDiv=true; hideMe()"  >Show Div</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="showDiv1=true; hideMe()"  >Show Div1</button>
    <div ng-show="showDiv">
        <div class="col-xl-3">
            <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="database_address">Потребител</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="activeItem.username" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Парола</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="password" ng-model="activeItem.password"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Оператор</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="username" ng-model="activeItem.name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Запазване</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <div ng-show="showDiv1">
        <div class="col-xl-3">
            <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="database_address">Потребител</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="activeItem.username" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Парола</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="password" ng-model="activeItem.password"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Оператор</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="username" ng-model="activeItem.name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Отлагане</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Angular code. Maybe it is not very right i think, but you will help me.
Thanks again!

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.hideMe = function(){
    console.log('hide the button');
    $scope.hide();
  }

});
```

Comment: since this is AngularJS maybe you can update the tag and remove Angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean way to show/hide forms with AngularJS Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245144/clean-way-to-show-hide-forms-with-angularjs-button)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set variable to false(ng-show), and then when user click the button, set variable to true:

Leave ng-click attribute like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="hideDiv()"  >Show Div</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="hideDiv1()"  >Show Div1</button>
```

Then:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.showDiv = false;
  $scope.showDiv1 = false;

  $scope.hideDiv = function(){
    if ($scope.showDiv) {
       $scope.showDiv = false;
    } else {
       $scope.showDiv = true;
    }
  }

  $scope.hideDiv1 = function(){
    if ($scope.showDiv1) {
       $scope.showDiv1 = false;
    } else {
       $scope.showDiv1 = true;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: But now when I click on one of the buttons they displayed two forms at the same time. And when hide function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo that may help you get started. Go over the docs for [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello, AngularJS"; 
  $scope.showHello = true;
  $scope.showBye = false;
    
  $scope.toggleBye = () => {
    $scope.showBye = !$scope.showBye;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="HelloController">
  <h2 ng-show="showHello">Hello</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="showBye">Bye</h2>
    <h2>Show always</h2>
 
    <button ng-click="toggleBye()">toggle bye</button>
  </div>
</body>
```